# Ignore div class align for navigation

Tags: css, html, web

I am trying to create a navigation menu at the top, on top of my full screen background image, the problem is that the way I did it below, will cause the 100vh section to move down so the bottom of the picture will not be visible, I tried to add the navigation in the `<div class="section valign-wrapper" id="home">` but this causes the nav to align vertically on the page so it won't be on top anymore, my question is: how can I put the navigation at the top of the page without moving the section down?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
          <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

      <!--Landing page-->
      <div class="section valign-wrapper" id="home">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="big-title"> Mijn naam is <br> Dan <br> en ik bouw websites en <br> applicaties. </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding the nav in the vertical aligned section and added:

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
          <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
          <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
      <!--Landing page-->
      <div class="section valign-wrapper" id="home">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="big-title"> Mijn naam is <br> Dan <br> en ik bouw websites en <br> applicaties. </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

with materizlize.css you can try wrapping your `nav` in a div and use class `navbar-fixed` for the `div`

`< div class="navbar-fixed">`

to make it permanently stay at top style the div as

`< div class="navbar-fixed" style="top:0px;position:fixed;">`

Comment: I tried this but I want the nav to stick to the top

Comment: check the code snippet, the nav is now fixed at top, hope this helps